# Postman-API Automation testing

Tags: collections, automation, postman, web-api-testing, postman-testcase

To test API using Postman what should be the best practice for **test management.**

We tried to create a fork for the folder in collection where developer created his APIs.
But if the developer do any changes on his collection no change will get reflected in our forked folder.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After forking a collection, the parent collection may be updated by others. If that happens, your fork will no longer be the same as the parent. In such circumstances, Postman notifies you about this change and allows you to pull these changes.

Read: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/version-control-for-collections/